# Invalid Syntax on tkinter's geometry widget

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I am trying to design a GUI for a bit of fun.
the purpose of the  code is to take what you entered into a "*entry widget*" and print it out in the terminal using the print() command when you press the submit button.

Two questions.

One: i keep getting an "*Invalid syntax*" error in the code both the root.geometry() and root.mainloop()

```
root.geometry("300x300")

root.mainloop()
```

two: is there a more effective way of getting the text from a tkinter entry widget and storing it in a variable. i would like to be able to store data from multiple entry widgets to multiple variables, and how can i do that.

Here is my full code.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def get_input():
    val = e1.get("1.0", "end-1-c")
    print(val)

lbl1 = Label(root, text = "Enter your name:").grid(row= "0", column= "0")
e1 = Entry(root, borderwidth = 5, width = 20).grid(row = "0", column = "1")
sbut = Button(root, text = "submit", command = get_input.grid(row= "1", column = "0")

root.geometry("300x300")

root.mainloop()
```

i used https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FueIPFqRyyY&t=85s for the code to save entry widget data to a varible

Thanks for any help

Comment: Read [AttributeError: NoneType object has no attribute ...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1101765/7414759)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not define a widget and `.grid()` it in the same line. You also had an `Invalid syntax` because you forgot a `)` at the line `sbut = Button(....grid(row= "1", column = "0"))`

You can try this :

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def get_input():
    val = e1.get()
    e1.delete("0", "end")
    print(val)

lbl1 = Label(root, text = "Enter your name:")
lbl1.grid(row= "0", column= "0")
e1 = Entry(root, borderwidth = 5, width = 20)
e1.grid(row = "0", column = "1")
sbut = Button(root, text = "submit", command = get_input)
sbut.grid(row= "1", column = "0")

root.geometry("300x300")

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks for your Help phoenixo. i will use your advice.

Comment: another advice for you : it is not advised to use `from tkinter import *`, you'd better use `import tkinter as tk` and then use `root = tk.Tk()`, `e1 = tk.Entry()` ...